# How to unstuck export window in test expert 3 during exporting to excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, load-testing

have some problem with exporting data to excel. Everything is ok but that popup "Export to excel - Values of channels are exporting" is stucking - every time. Below screen - I tried to reinstall office, install new version of office, remove keys from register etc. What is funny - when im trying export to word everything works fine without stucking.
[Problem with export to excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yyan.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How did you export? Did you use other application to export?